# Как узнать серийный номер жесткого диска, на котором стоит система?

Tags: c++, winapi

Я у винды могу запросить серийный номер жесткого диска - выглядит примерно вот так:

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* enumerator = getEnumerator(services, _bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"));
....
getEnumeratorItem(obj, &info, L"SerialNumber");
```

Как узнать на котором системная или моя программа?

Comment: См. `Win32_Volume.SerialNumber` для `BootVolume = 'True'`

Comment: @Akina, ну что то не нашел BootVolume тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/vdswmi/win32-volume#properties

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE8Zp.png

Comment: Возможно, требуется Windows 7? проверь `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume` на своей системе.

Comment: @Akina, да, 7 требуется, wmi классы могут не работать получается?

Comment: @Akina, приложение классное, вот только это похоже серийный номер локального диска, а мне надо прям харда... Придется использовать это свойство с моими старыми , чтобы найти то что мне нужно

Comment: Загрузочный, системный - это по-любому логический диск и том. Вам надо найти маппинг томов на физические устройства (что-то типа DiskToPartition), и только тогда Вы доберётесь до девайсов и сможете запросить сериал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116298/discussion-between-aptem-f-and-akina).